# Java Program to reverse individual words in the sentence

Tags: java

I am trying to write a java program that reverses every individual word in a sentence. For example, if the sentence is **"Hello World. Hello Java."**, the output should be **"olleH dlroW. olleH avaJ"**. I am able to do the reverse but the output I am getting is **"olleH .dlroW olleH .avaJ"** where even the dot is getting reversed which should not happen. Can somebody help me fix it?

Thank you!!

I tried something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReverseWords {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Enter a string to be reversed:");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String reverse = "";

        while(input.hasNextLine())
        {
            String str = input.next();
            for(int i = str.length()-1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                reverse = reverse + str.charAt(i);
            }
            reverse += " ";
            System.out.println(reverse);
        }
    }

}
```

**Expected output:** olleH dlroW. olleH avaJ.

**Output I am getting:**

olleH

olleH .dlroW

olleH .dlroW olleH

olleH .dlroW olleH .avaJ

Comment: Are you allowed to use the `StringBuilder` class?

Comment: `next()` returns *tokens*, not *words*, so don't use `next()` for this. Read the entire line with `nextLine()`, which is also consistent with your use of `hasNextLine()`, then locate the words in that line of text and reverse them, one at a time. Said differently, take a **step back, and re-think** what needs to be done. --- Attempting to fix your current code is not the right answer, and you correctly don't seem to just want a full solution handed to you (very good!!), so this is the best advice we can give you (for now). Ask another question is your next solution doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the java 8 solution, you may need to modify `replaceChar` method if you want to restrict other special characters.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "Hello World. Hello Java.";
    String collect = Arrays.stream(str.split("\\s+"))  // split sentences into words
            .map(s -> new StringBuffer(s))             // converting to StringBuffer
            .map(s -> s.reverse())                     // reversing the string
            .map(s -> replaceChar(s))                  // replace first char if it is dot
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));         // join all the words

    System.out.println(collect);

}

private static String replaceChar(StringBuffer stringBuffer) {
    if(stringBuffer.charAt(0) == '.') {
        stringBuffer.deleteCharAt(0);
        return stringBuffer.toString() + ".";
    }

    return stringBuffer.toString();
}
```

If you want to do it in the imperative style you can modify your code as below:

```
String str = "Hello World. Hello Java.";
String[] tokens = str.split("\\s+");
String reverseString = "";
for (String token : tokens) {
    String reverse = "";
    for (int i = token.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        reverse = reverse + token.charAt(i);
    }
    if(reverse.charAt(0) == '.') {
        reverse = reverse.substring(1) + ".";
    }
    reverseString = reverseString + " " + reverse;
}
System.out.println(reverseString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed a little in your code to handle . in words.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Enter a string to be reversed:");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String reverse = "";

        while(input.hasNextLine())
        {
            String str = input.next();
            if(str.contains(".")){
                str = str.replace(".","");
                for(int i = str.length()-1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    reverse = reverse + str.charAt(i);
                }
                reverse = reverse+".";
            }
            else{
                for(int i = str.length()-1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    reverse = reverse + str.charAt(i);
                }
            }
            reverse += " ";
            System.out.println(reverse);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work if `.` char is in the middle of String. `str.contains(".")` will be true for `He.llo` also

Comment: Yes, i modified for test case mentioned here. Although u can keep the index of dot and after reverse of word append dot at the index.